# CSS absolute positioning- do I need to specify top, right, bottom AND left?

Tags: css

I have an element in my stylesheet that is absolute positioned and noticed that all four directions are listed as `0`:

```
input.flip + label:before, input.flip + label:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2.2em;
}
```

In a case where all directions are `0`, is it necessary to specify all of them, or would it be just as good to only specify `top` and `left`?

```
input.flip + label:before, input.flip + label:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2.2em;
}
```

Comment: I think, top and left will work

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: It is important because you aren't specifying height or width anywhere. All four = 0 means height = 100% and width = 100% if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here , setting all coordonates to zero tells the element to cover the whole parent (positionned).if label is position:relative or fixed or absolute it will cover it .

it is similar to

```
top:0;
left:0;
height:100%;
width:100%;
```

But it can have another purpose for element sized, adding margin:auto; will center element into the parent positioned. if there is no parent positionned, then the viewport come the reference.
example

```css
input,
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2.2em;
  margin: auto;
}

div {
  background: lime;/* show me */
}

input {
  z-index: 1;/* let me be on top */
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="i have a defaut size" />
<div> well i have size that content, coordonates or height/width ,  shall give me </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `absolute`, `relative` or `fixed` position, you just need to specify `Vertically` position and `Horizontally` position. So when you set `right` offset, you don't need to set the other horizontal offset propery (`left`).

**When you use both of `left` and `right` properties, in some cases it means 100% with.**

So, it is OK to use only `left` and `top` or just `right` and `bottom` properties.

Comment: Sure, it's "ok" to, but it won't do the same thing at all.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yes, I mean only one of horizontal offset and one of vertical offset properties is enough.